# Node Index.js is not working - Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, syntax-error

When trying to run node index.js, I keep getting the error message below:

```
app.use(morgan)('common'));
                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

My code is below:

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// const methodOverride = require("method-override");

app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send("Something broke!");
});

let movies = [
    {
      title: "Snatch",
      year: "2000",
      genre: "Crime Comedy"
    },
    {
      title: "Pretty in Pink",
      year: "1986",
      genre: "Teen/Romance/Comedy"
    },
    {
      title: "Good Will Hunting",
      year: "1997",
      genre: "Drama"
    },
    {
      title: "Kung Fu Panda",
      year: "2008",
      genre: "Animated/Kids"
    },
    {
      title: "Rocknrolla",
      year: "2008",
      genre: "Crime Comedy"
    },
    {
      title: "Always Be My Maybe",
      year: "2019",
      genre: "Romantic Comedy"
    },
    {
      title: "Forrest Gump",
      year: "1994",
      genre: "Drama"
    },
    {
      title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
      year: "1994",
      genre: "Drama"
    },
    {
      title: "The Green Mile",
      year: "1999",
      genre: "Drama"
    },
    {
      title: "The Departed",
      year: "2006",
      genre: "Drama"
    }
  ],
  users = [
    {
      username: "User A",
      id: "1"
    },
    {
      username: "User B",
      id: "2"
    },
    {
      username: "User C",
      id: "3"
    },
    {
      username: "User D",
      id: "4"
    },
    {
      username: "User E",
      id: "5"
    }
  ],
  directors = [
    {
      name: "Steven Spielburg",
      birthYear: "1946"
    },
    {
      name: "Martin Scorsese",
      birthYear: "1942"
    },
    {
      name: "Quentin Tarantino",
      birthYear: "1963"
    },
    {
      name: "Tim Burton",
      birthYear: "1958"
    },
    {
      name: "Francis Ford Coppola",
      birthYear: "1939"
    },
    {
      name: "Christopher Nolan",
      birthYear: "1970"
    },
    {
      name: "David Fincher",
      birthYear: "1962"
    },
    {
      name: "Spike Lee",
      birthYear: "1957"
    },
    {
      name: "Ridley Scott",
      birthYear: "1937"
    },
    {
      name: "Kathryn Bigelow",
      birthYear: "1951"
    }
  ];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to my movie club!");
});

app.get("/movies", (req, res) => {
  res.json(movies);
});

app.get("/movies/:title", (req, res) => {
  res.json(
    movies.find(movie => {
      return movie.title === req.params.title;
    })
  );
});

// data about the genre by title
app.get("movies/:title", (req, res) => {
  res.json(
    movies.find(movie => {
      return movie.title === req.params.title;
    })
  );
});

//list of all the users
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  console.log("test");
  res.json(users);
});

//info on director by name
app.get("/directors/:name", (req, res) => {
  res.json(
    directors.find(director => {
      return director.name === req.params.name;
    })
  );
});

//user's data by name
app.get("/users/:username", (req, res) => {
  res.json(
    users.find(user => {
      return user.username === req.params.username;
    })
  );
});

//adding new user
app.post("/users", (req, res) => {
  let newUser = req.body;

  if (!newUser.username) {
    const message = "Missing name in request body";
    res.status(400).send(message);
  } else {
    newUser.id = uuid.v4();
    users.push(newUser);
    res.status(201).send(newUser);
  }
});

// Deletes a user by ID
app.delete("/users/:id", (req, res) => {
  let user = users.find(user => {
    return user.id === req.params.id;
  });

  if (user) {
    users = users.filter(obj => {
      return obj.id !== req.params.id;
    });
    res.status(201).send("User " + req.params.id + " was deleted.");
  }
});

// Add a movie to favorites
app.post("/users/:username/favorites", (req, res) => {
  let newfavorite = req.body;

  if (!newfavorite.title) {
    const message = "Missing title in request body";
    res.status(400).send(message);
  } else {
    res.send("Succesful POST request - new title added to favs.");
  }
});

// Remove a movie from favorites
app.delete("/users/:username/favorites", (req, res) => {
  let toRemove = req.body;

  if (!toRemove.title) {
    const message = "Missing title in request body";
    res.status(400).send(message);
  } else {
    res.send("Succesful DELETE request - title removed from favs.");
  }
});

// Update the username
app.put("/users/:username", (req, res) => {
  let user = users.find(user => {
    return user.username === req.params.username;
  });

  if (user) {
    user[req.params.username] = parseInt(req.params.username);
    res
      .status(201)
      .send(
        "Sucsessful PUT request: User " +
          req.params.username +
          " changed his username."
      );
  } else {
    res
      .status(404)
      .send("User with the name " + req.params.username + " was not found.");
  }
});

//list of favs of a single user
app.get("/users/:username/favorites", (req, res) => {
  res.send(
    "Successful GET request returning data on favorite movies of a single user."
  );
});

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send("Something broke!");
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("movie_api is listening on port 8080.");
});
```

I believe my code is correct, so not sure why the syntax error is coming up. My linter didn't come up with any errors. Also having an issue getting this to work in Postman, but that is a separate issue. If I can get node to work, I can tackle that next. I'm sure the solution is simple, but having a tough time trying to figure it out.

Comment: Try rewriting the line

Comment: Save your file after editing before running

Comment: @PyxlDavon Tried that - still not working

Comment: @Ricky Mo tried that as well - still no luck